# Order by specific word in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following data:
[image]

I want to show all invoice most recent having 'Due' status first. How can I order this data.

N.B: I am using Mysql database.

Comment: You have only 2 status? Due and Paid?

Comment: Yes. But  any additional status will be added like 'abc'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should sort Due, Paid and others in order:

```
SELECT Date, Invoice, ProductName, Qty, Rate, TotalPrice, PaymentStatus, PaymentType
FROM xxxTable
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN PaymentStatus LIKE "%Due%" then 1 
    WHEN PaymentStatus LIKE "%Paid%"  then 2 
    ELSE 3 
END
```

Comment: Thank you. But how to add additional order criteria for most recent data, i.e: order invoice_id by descending?

Comment: can't you just add by adding comma? like ,AnotherColumn;

Comment: Solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Date
     , Invoice
     , ProductName
     , Qty
     , Rate
     , TotalPrice
     , PaymentStatus
     , PaymentType
  FROM xxxTable
 ORDER
    BY PaymentStatus = 'Due' DESC 
     , date DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
   select   *
   from     yourtable
   order by
            `Payment Status`
            ,Date desc
```